# REQL Date and time queries

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

My documents contain the following fields:

```
"valid_from":  "Mar 17 08:55:04 2011 GMT"
"valid_to":  "Mar 16 08:55:04 2017 GMT"
```

My base query currently looks like this:

```
r.db('items').table('token')
```

1. How can I query to only retrieve/filter the documents between the current date-time (now) and the "valid_to" field? i.e. anything with a "valid_to" date that is less than the current date/time is considered expired.
2. Calculate the number of days between the "valid_from" and "valid_to" fields. i.e. Determine the validity period in days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**#1**

So, basically you want all documents that still haven't expired? (`valid_to`) is in the future?

In order to do that, you should definitely use RethinkDB time/date functions. In order to do though, you have to create a time instance with either [`r.time`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/time/) or [`r. ISO8601`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/iso8601/). An example of this is:

```
r.table('tokens')
  .insert({
    "valid_from": r.ISO8601("2011-03-17T08:55:04-07:00"),
    "valid_to": r.ISO8601("2017-03-17T08:55:04-07:00")
  })
```

Once you've inserted/update the documents using these functions, you can query them using RethinkDB's time/date functions. I you want all documents where `valid_to` is in the future, you can do this:

```
r.table('tokens')
  .filter(r.row['valid_to'] > r.now())
```

If you want to get all documents where `valid_to` is in the future and `valid_from` is in the past, you can do this:

```
r.table('tokens')
  .filter(r.row['valid_to'] > r.now())
  .filter(r.row['valid_from'] < r.now())
```

**#2**

If both these properties (`valid_to` and `valid_from`) are time/date objects, you can add a `days` property to each document by doing the following:

```
r.table('tokens')
  .merge({
    // Subtract the two properties. Divide by seconds * minutes * hours
    "days": (r.row['valid_to'] - r.row['valid_from']) / (60 * 60 * 24)
  })
```

**The Python Code**

```
import rethinkdb as r
conn = r.connect()
cursor = r.table('30715780').filter(r.row['valid_to'] < r.now()).count().run(conn)
print list(cursor)
```

Comment: Jorge, I'm following your example here but for some reason no data is returned when running: r.table('tokens').filter(r.row['valid_to'] > r.now()). Any idea why?

Comment: OK. I managed to make it work. I guess the syntax was changed: r.table('tokens').filter(r.row('valid_to').gt(r.now()))

Comment: What language where you using? `>` and `<` work in some languages only, since it does this by operator overloading. JavaScript is not one of those languages.

Comment: I am using javascript (nodejs), so that's probably it, but it also didn't work when running from the Web admin's data explorer... just in case anyone else tries to use it. Thanks!